# Simple SET PROBLEM

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If A ⊂ B , which of the following is always true?

a.)  A\B = Ø

b.)  n(A) < n(B)

a is the correct answer

Why is it not letter b? and kindly explain why is it a?

Thanks :)!

Comment: How do you define $\subset$?  Is it a subset of or a proper subset of?

Comment: ignore the cardinals , just thought of the cardinality in option b hahah... It's proper subset of

Answer (score 2):

For b), you have to consider infinite sets. Consider the two sets $\mathbb{N}_{\geq 0}$ and $\mathbb{N}_{> 0}$. Clearly, $\mathbb{N}_{> 0}\subset\mathbb{N}_{\geq 0}$, since $\mathbb{N}_{\geq 0}=\mathbb{N}_{> 0}\cup\{0\}$. However, one can define a bijection between the two sets ($k\rightarrow k-1$), thus, their cardinality is the same ($n(\mathbb{N}_{> 0})=n(\mathbb{N}_{\geq 0})$).

Comment: Furthermore, it’s possible that the author of the problem uses $\subset$ for non-strict inclusion, so that his $A\subset B$ is my $A\subseteq B$. In that case (b) need not be true even for finite $A$ and $B$.